# Is it possible to have a spot instance mount a particular EBS volume as its root disk when started?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

For example, in a scenario where you have an auto-scaling group of size 1 that launches a spot instance which continually uses the same root EBS volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively as far as I am aware, and not the root volume. You can however create a launch script to mount the volume as a secondary drive when the instance is spun up

Comment: Can you use pivot_root to remap the secondary volume as the root fs in the launch script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with autoscaling instances (the "cattle" service model).

But if you use a "pet" service model, you can now ([since 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-ec2-spot-can-now-stop-and-start-your-spot-instances/)) create a spot request and enable "Maintain target capacity" with "Interruption behavior: Stop" and a single availability zone. This way the root volume of the spot instance will be preserved even if it is temporarily interrupted.

I think (I did not check that) you can now convert a normal (pet-type) EC2 instance to a spot like this:

- create spot instance with some public AMI,
- stop the spot instance ([possible since January 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/amazon-ec2-spot-instances-stopped-started-similar-to-on-demand-instances/)),
- detach root volume from spot instance,
- delete detached root volume,
- stop the normal instance,
- create snapshot of normal instance root volume, just in case,
- detach root volume from normal instance,
- attach root volume to spot instance,
- terminate normal instance,
- start spot instance.

There's also a script, [ec2-spot-converter](https://github.com/jcjorel/ec2-spot-converter), that does something similar by creating a temporary AMI image: