# How to select snapshot for root EBS volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have a custom AMI, with a corresponding EBS snapshot, made some time earlier. Recently, I have decided to create a newer EBS snapshot to reflect some software updates. Then I wanted to submit a **spot instance** request, so that the new instance would use the **new snapshot**. Based on AWS documentation, it seems that, in order to achieve this, I have to create a new AMI, based on the new EBS snapshot as **root volume**. However, it appears that the only way to create a new AMI is to use an existing or running EC2 instance as a base. But, since any existing or running instances use one of the previous snapshots, it appears to be a **catch-22** situation. Am I missing something? What is the correct **sequence of steps** to create a new AMI off of the instance with updated file system or via snapshot of that file system? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve my problem. The answer by Andrew Lusk pointed me to the right direction. However, my current environment makes me prefer a GUI option versus the command line one. But, he is incorrect in stating that GUI console option doesn't exist for **creating a new AMI from an EBS snapshot**. I have researched a little bit more and found that this option indeed exists. The solution is described in this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html. I have already used the above-mentioned guidelines to create and launch a new AMI, based on my EBS snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make a new AMI from an EBS snapshot.  The console doesn't let you do this; you should use the command line tools.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RegisterImage.html

You want 'ec2-register -s snap-XXXXXXXX'.

Comment: Andrew, greatly appreciate your help! Upvoting now, will accept a bit later, if there will be no more comprehensive answers. What do think about this: http://serverfault.com/questions/597455/keeping-users-filesystem-persistent-across-aws-ec2-spot-instances?