# auto-attach EBS volume to a Spot instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-ebs

I need some persistent storage across spot terminations.

My approach to solve the problem is

1. Write a startup script that attaches and mounts the persistent volume
2. Snapshot this state and register a private AMI
3. Launch Spot instances based of the private AMI

searches in this forum [[1](https://serverfault.com/questions/448043/auto-attach-ebs-volume-to-a-new-spot-instance)] suggests this is the correct procedure

My startup script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "executing startup script"

# attach the EBS volume to this machine
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-7bef1d96  --instance-id  $(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id ) --device /dev/xvdg

sleep  10

# mount the attached EBS volume
echo "mounting the  attached volume"
sudo mount /dev/xvdg1 /home/ubuntu/persistent/

#run script
echo "starting the  dummy program in background"
python2 persistent/dummyProgram.py &
```

The script works perfectly if executed manually. However when it is executed by cron the  only the echo statement are executed

the crontab task is

```
@reboot /path/to/startupScript.sh
```

How do I solve this problem?

**The corrected  crontab entry reads :**

```
USER=username
PATH=content of $PATH
@reboot /path/to/startupScript.sh
```

Comment: why don't you put this into userdata instead of cron? that's why they are made for: execute some code at startup. By using cron, you expose yourself to path issues that you would probably not have with userdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason why commands would not be running when invoked from a crontab script is that they are not on the PATH environment variable.  Crontab entries run with a minimal set of environment variables by default.

Comment: or give the *full path* for `aws`, `sudo`, and `python2`.

Answer (score 0):

While `cron` could definitely get the job done, the canonical way to do this is to specify a `user-data` script that runs when the spot instance is launched. With the AWS CLI's `request-spot-instance` this is specified in JSON using the `--launch-specification` argument.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/request-spot-instances.html

This section can be a small shell script and allows you to *change the volume-id* should that ever be necessary instead of hardcoding that into the AMI.

Comment: I tried using user-data; But for some reason I failed to make it work.
so I settled for `cron`
I didn,t notice of the hardcoded volume id but as it's not much of a issue I decided to ignore it for now